# Chrome DevTool JavaScript Source turn grey, and variable don't show value when cursor hover

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

All The JavaScript Code turn grey like the text style without color. And the variable value don't show as usual? I didn't use webpack in the code, Can anybody Tell me Why?[image]

[image]

As the second picture, the keyword are colored. It turns normal this morning, but I still don't know why. I restarted the Chrome and the PC, but it was still. And it works today.

Comment: I don't see what gets grey!?

Comment: @JohnArcher just as the second picture, that's normal.

Comment: You mean you got no syntax highlighting in the first picture!? But the variable values _are_ shown. See the orange backgrounded area which says `res = { data: {...},`.

Comment: @JohnArcher yes